# How to install/uninstall a module on button click in openerp?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

can anyone help me with the code to install and uninstall a module on button click in OpenERP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a module and want to be abble to install it to OpenERP, you just have to include the following line in your `__openerp__.py`

```
 'installable': True,
```

And make sure also that your module is inside an addons path that is included on your configuration file.

This way, you will be able to search for you module and install it.